# Java program to create a square matrix with series of numbers where first two numbers are are given

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

Wrote a Java program to create a square matrix with series of numbers where first two numbers are are given and the rest of the number to be filled in accordance with the first two numbers and its difference.

> Eg1: if **first number 2** and **second number 5**, the difference between them is **3** and if the matrix is 3X3, then the expected output is:
> 2,5,8,
> 11,14,17
> 20,23,26

> Eg1: if **first number 3** and **second number 7**, the difference between them is **4** and if the matrix size is 5, then the expected output is:
> 3,7,11,15,19
> 23,27,31,35,39
> 43,47,51,55,59
> 63,67,71,75,79
> 83,87,91,95,99

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareMatrixWithSeries {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the first integer: ");
        int first = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the second integer: ");
        int second = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the size of the square matrix: ");
        int size = scanner.nextInt();

        int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];

        // Fill the matrix with the series of numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                    matrix[i][j] = first;
                } else if (i == 0 && j == 1) {
                    matrix[i][j] = second;
                } else if (i==0){
                    matrix[i][j] = first + (j+1)*(second-first);
                } else {
                    matrix[i][j] = first + (size+j+i-1)*(second-first);
                }
            }
        }

        // Print the matrix
        System.out.println("Square Matrix with the Series of Numbers:");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

As given in eg1, the above code's output is :

> 2 5 11 
> 11 14 17 
> 14 17 20

Tried many variations to fill the matrix and couldn't find the bug in the code.

Comment: “in accordance with the first two numbers and its difference” is not sufficient to describe the intended logic. Giving one example of input and expected output isn’t describing the problem either.

Comment: But, if I got it correctly, your task is basically to generate a multiplication table with offset whose first two numbers are provided and, for some reason, has to be put into a matrix. Then, let the implementation follow this order, first, think about generating the sequence of numbers, then put it into the matrix. Do not use the matrix coordinates to calculate the position in the sequence. That’s possible but obsolete. For example, `for(int i = 0, value = first, difference = second - first; i < size; i++) { for(int j = 0; j < size; j++, value += difference) { matrix[i][j] = value; } }`

Comment: *"The above code's output is : ..."* Given what input (first, second, third)? Please edit the question to include that.

Answer (score 1):

As your elements are sequential, you can just keep track of the `current` value and update it by the `difference` after putting an element in the matrix. You don't need the `if-else` ladder inside the loop.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareMatrixWithSeries {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the first integer: ");
        int first = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the second integer: ");
        int second = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the size of the square matrix: ");
        int size = scanner.nextInt();

        int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];

        int curr = first; // <-- current value is the first number
        int diff = second - first; // <--- save the difference so that you don't 
                                    // need to calculate every time
        // Fill the matrix with the series of numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = curr; // <--- put the current value in the matrix
                curr += diff; // <--- update the current value by adding the difference
            }
        }

        // Print the matrix
        System.out.println("Square Matrix with the Series of Numbers:");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - like always - lets start from the beginning.
You scan a first number, then a second one, calculate the difference between these two and create numbers afterwards which add the difference to the predecessor to create a new number.

Sure - you can create a square matrix but this is here not necessary. Just create a normal matrix for size*size elements. You need only in the end to split up the display to the wanted output. Here is my solution:

```
// -- your inputs stays the same
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the first integer: ");
    int first = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the second integer: ");
    int second = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the size of the square matrix: ");
    int size = scanner.nextInt();        

// -- the normal matrix and the needed definitions   
    int[] matrix = new int[size * size];
    
    matrix[0] = first;
    matrix[1] = second;
    int difference = second - first;
    
// -- the calculation
    for (int i0=2; i0<matrix.length; i0++) {
        matrix[i0] = matrix[i0-1] + difference;
    }

// -- your output
    System.out.println("Square Matrix with the Series of Numbers:");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i*size + j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

You get the desired output and it is fairly easy to calculate even other rules.
Happy coding.

Comment: Answers generated from chatgpt are banned on SO
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: @Melvin, Your suggestion works for 1D Array, but my Problem is to work with a 2D Array

Comment: I HAVE created this on my own and programmed in Netbeans.  There is no need to use a chatbot for this simply programs.

Stop the false accusation @ZahidKhan

Comment: @NIMISHAN You map the 2D-Array out of the 1D-Array. You do not need to calculate it in first hand in 2D.

Comment: @Melvin, Rest of my program follows with some Calculations like Product of the Diagonal Elements, finding Transpose and so on, so I tried to work directly with 2D array. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the row and column count to get the factor to multiply with:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the first integer: ");
    int first = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the second integer: ");
    int second = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the size of the square matrix: ");
    int size = scanner.nextInt();

    int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = first + ((i * size + j) * (second - first));
        }
    }
```